# Convert a File to Array in c# using System.IO

Tags: c#, arrays, file, byte

I have a problem in converting my file into a byte array. So I have researched that the most reliable way of doing so is thru this :

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
```

The problem is, our system already has classes: `System.cs` and `File.cs`. It is overlapping with with the above aforementioned method. The word `File` and `System` uses my existing classes as reference. Is there other way to do this ? TIA

Comment: Ask your teammate, they must do it intentionally. They might have custom methods to replace .net standard methods.

Comment: `global::System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes( filename );`

Comment: @SirRufo This solved my problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do:
`using MsSystem = System;`

Then in your code:
`byte[] bytes = MsSystem.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);`

Or; you can use global refers to the global namespace, it can be used to solve problems whereby you may redefine types. For example:

```
class foo
{
    class System
    {

    }

}
```

Usage:

`global::System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);`

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to use named imports either for your own classes or for the original System and File types. So e.g. if you wanted to use named imports for the standard library Files type you could do like this to avoid the names clashing:

```
using SystemFiles = System.IO.File;
```

This link also has an example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: `using static directive`**

```
using static System.IO.File;
...
ReadAllBytes(filename);
```

**Option 2: Create separate class wrapping the method**

```
using System.IO;
...
public static class FileReader
{
    public static byte[] ReadAllBytes(string filename) => File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
}
```

Usage:

```
 FileReader.ReadAllBytes(filename);
```

**Option 3: Use `global` namespace**

```
global::System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
```